# HDD doesn't show up in BIOS but does show up in GParted

Tags: hard-drive, bios, gparted

I'm trying to fix my friend's laptop, but I've encountered a problem I have no idea how to solve or what the problem is.

There is a HDD (Hitachi) that cannot be detected by the BIOS, but if i run GParted (from the Ultimate Boot CD) the drive and its partitions are clearly visible and mountable.

I've tried putting the HDD in my own laptop, but the BIOS doesn't detect it either.

I already tried restoring the BIOS to default settings. When I run HDAT2, it says the following:

```
Controller=Master 
Base/CTRL=F110h/F102H
IRQ=10
Mode=UDMA5/ATA100
CTRL/Device= SATA/SATA SATA2 NCQ HIPM DIPM 4K [Direct Access]

!DCO: FROZEN
!SECURITY: FROZEN
!SMART: ERROR
!POWER: ACTIVE

!ATA_MODE: UDMA5/ATA1000
```

The whole 'frozen' ' error' thing doesn't look so good, but if GParted can still access the drive, there must be a way to fix this, no?

Comment: See if this link helps: http://www.hdat2.com/hdat2_faq.html

Comment: I don't really see something that can help me. But I also don't really know what I am looking for.

Comment: See Q2 at that link.

Comment: I don't understand the following scentence (English is not my first language):
"If you have SATA drive in Security and/or DCO frozen state, simple solution is connect this drive to PC with BIOS which doesn't set security mode."

Should I connect the drive while the PC is on?

Comment: English apparently wasn't the first language of the article's author, either. :-)  The article is talking about finding another computer with a different BIOS (although it isn't clear how you know ahead of time whether that one sets security mode).  As general practice, it is better not to connect and disconnect things while the power is on, and you don't want to jar the drive while it is powered up.  However, you can do it with hard drives as long as you are careful.  In this case, you don't want the other computer trying to boot from your drive so you don't have much choice.

Comment: Okay, so I tried this:  
1) I put the drive in my laptop (as a primary) (while the power was off). Here my laptop also couldn't boot from it (nowhere to be found in the BIOS).  
2) I put the drive in my laptop (as a secondary) where having my own drive as primary. The secondary drive (my friend's) did not appear in the BIOS but it did appear in Windows Explorer. I can navigate the file without a problem. (Running Avast scan now btw)

3) I also put my own HDD in my friend's laptop. Here the BIOS found it and I could boot into my OS's.

Comment: after the scan is complete I will try 1) again with the power on, like sugested

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem.

While the drive was in my laptop as a "secondary drive", I ran GParted and turned the boot flag of the drive's boot partition off and on again. No idea why this worked, but it seems to have done the trick!